# Deploying react web application on AWS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment

I am looking to deploy my nodejs React web application on AWS. Currently I deployed my application on Microsoft's Azure and there is was pretty simple. I just had to add an App Service and give my git repository as the source to it. That took care of hosting my application. I am not getting a way like to do it on AWS. I am looking for something like that. How should I do it in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** for this. Elastic Beanstalk is the PaaS offering which  is an easy-to-use service for deploying and scaling web applications and services developed with Java, .NET, PHP, Node.js, Python, Ruby, Go, and Docker on familiar servers such as Apache, Nginx, Passenger, and IIS. It is similar to Microsoft Azure App services.

You can simply upload your code and Elastic Beanstalk automatically handles the deployment, from capacity provisioning, load balancing, auto-scaling to application health monitoring. At the same time, you retain full control over the AWS resources powering your application and can access the underlying resources at any time.

You can go through the tutorial for deploying your node.js app here- [Deploying an Express Application to Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html?carousel=true)

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy ways to do this in a Serverless manner is to use the new AWS Mobile CLI:

```
npm install -g awsmobile-cli
```

Then initialize and publish:

```
cd ./myproj
awsmobile init #answer some questions
awsmobile publish
```

This will setup an S3 bucket with CloudFront configured as your CDN to host your web assets. Your NodeJS app can be hosted in a Lambda function which is protected by API Gateway. A good way to configure the connection and authorzation from the client is to use AWS Amplify in your React application:

```
npm install aws-amplify --save
npm install aws-amplify-react --save
```

Then after doing an `Amplify.configure(your_config_object` you can connect to API gateway which calls your Lambda:

```
let apiName = 'MyApiName';
let path = '/path'; 
let myInit = { // OPTIONAL
    headers: {} // OPTIONAL
}
API.get(apiName, path, myInit).then(response => {
    // Add your code here
});
```

This will be a signed request to your AWS resources.

More here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/web-getting-started.html